# WordPress background URL doesn't show image

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack, sass, wordpress-theming

I am building a WordPress theme from scratch. I am trying to learn from a youtube video (https://youtu.be/TlmDsU8GirU?t=3670) but even though I do exactly the same it still doesn't work.
I want to add an image as a background. The following code is the same as in the video but it doesn't work. [I get this message in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruong.png).
When adding instead writing '/images/background.jpeg' [I get this message, but still nothing is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/219V9.png).
When writing '../images/background.jpeg' [I get the same message over and over again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O09yL.png), but nothing works.

app.scss

```
#hero {
height: 550px;
width:100%;
background: url('images/background.jpeg') #f0f0f0;}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
})
.js('src/app.js', './')
    .sass('src/app.scss', './');
```

front-page.php

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div id="hero">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <h1>My website</h1>
    </div>

</div>



<?php get_footer();?>
```

This is my path (I think? The folders at least)
[image: This is my path (I think? The folders at least)]

Comment: There might be a problem with your image path. Try full url (C:/users/...) and see if it works. Be sure to just use this for checking, and you have to include your image in your project folder later.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest mistake is

```
 `background: url('images/background.jpeg') #f0f0f0;}`  you can't use color with background-image.
```

You can use -

{
    background: url('../images/background.jpeg'); background-color:background: #f0f0f0;  }

because your css must be in css folder while your image might be outside css folder in images or

```
background: url('./images/background.jpeg');
```

if in

```
style.css

    background: url('./assets/images/background.jpeg');
```

## it depends upon our directory structure of files.

try using these paths , else Can you show your directory structure of your files & `css` so that we can see the path you might be following.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. (I added my directory in the post).

Comment: It should work with `background-image: url('./images/background.jpg'); ` or `background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');` #You are using scss for styling . is that right then you must do it in scss way or style background in style.css    using `background-image: url('/images/background.jpg');`

Comment: the compiled css is in the same level as images folder, so it should be `('images/background.jpeg')`